# Nuxt.js 2.13 full static still try to fetch data from apollo on routing

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

- Nuxt.js 2.13
- target: static
- @nuxtjs/apollo
- data coming from an headless cms

example:

```
import blogQuery from '~/apollo/queries/blog.gql'

data () {
  return {
    blog: []
  }
},
apollo: {
  blog: {
    query: blogQuery
  }
}
```

- `nuxt build && nuxt export`

I'd expect no more data fetch, but this is still happening on the exported static website

What can be going wrong?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/339), apollo smart queries aren't supported with the new target: static. You need to use asyncData or the new fetch (for components and layouts)